# How to enable Word Wrap in VS Code suggestion descriptions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I just need to enable Word Wrap in IntelliSense, not in the editor.

Screenshot of Python “sort” method in VS Code:
[image: Screenshot of Python “sort” method in VS Code]

Comment: for me the text of the tooltip has word wrap, the function definition has not but it has syntax highlighting (probably marked as `code` in the markdown, I use Pylance `v2022.1.3`

Comment: Thank you, @rioV8. This Pylance extension, aside from function definition, fixes the issue! I also enabled `Complete Function Parens: Add parentheses to function completions.` in `@ext:ms-python.vscode-pylance`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, this problem was partially solved by installing the Pylance extension, which caused the function description to have word wrapping expect for the function definition part.